# Where is the output of a Terminal (Gnome Terminal) stored

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, output

First of all, this is not a question about `history`, which stores all the entered commands.

I have on my workstation at work several open Terminals from which I launch simulations, examine the output and where occasionally error messages are displayed.

In `Gnome Terminal` there is a setting controlling the length of the scroll back, in my case the setting is set to be just shy of 10000 lines.

Now my question: How can I search the scroll-back?

In my case I want to check whether a recent error message occurred previously.
Yes, I can scroll back and use my eyeballs to search for the error message in question.
But for several Terminals which are potentially up to 10000 lines long, that means a serious time spent scrolling.

I assume the information in the scroll-back needs to be stored somewhere, and if is stored somewhere it might actually be searchable.

[Edit: corrected the question to be about Gnome Terminal.]

Comment: Where's this Bash setting for scrollback?

Comment: @Oli presumably he's talking of the terminal's scrollback buffer.

Comment: It isn't stored in a file, and I don't think Gnome Terminal offers this feature. You can save all the output to file and then search the file - http://askubuntu.com/q/161935/158442 This cannot be done post-fact.

Comment: My language setting is German, but when I translate it is `Edit` -> `Profile settings` and then a tab named `Bildlauf` in German. The version is Gnome Terminal 3.4.1.1. Sorry for posting initially, that its bash.

Comment: I am saving the output of the simulation application I call in a file. However, I often view the log files and the error messages go also to the Terminal.

Comment: if you use gnome-terminal you can search error message in output  terminal window, there is already `search` in top bar in terminal

Comment: I just used the search function successfully. That was maybe too obvious. However, if there was an error of warning message that is printed frequently, then an automated search via the command line would be time saving. Thus, my question is still upright. Where or how is this data stored?

Comment: @DohnJoe in memory. That's why you have to save it separately in a file. The linked question in my comment above deals with that (this is different from IO redirection).

Comment: Also note that some other programs, such as Putty offer an option to save to a file. Terminator has a plugin which can also do the same.

Comment: @muru: ok, that answers my question. So by default, it is not stored anywhere but in RAM.

Answer (score 3):

If the output produced by your scripts is very important to you (to look for error, warning, actions that were run and so on), then you shouldn't rely on the display of the console you're using.

You have to redirect the output of your scripts to some files, this has advantages :

- you are no more bounded to the number of lines in the scroll buffer of the console you are using
- you can archive the result for as long as you want to be able to retrieve what was done, even some days/weeks/months after you effectively run the script
- you can have the errors logged to a dedicated file, different from the informational messages, making it more easy to find errors. (if the commands used in your scripts send error to STDERR and information to STDOUT).
- you can even log to a file while still displaying output on the terminal is you use the command `tee`.

So, you can do this :

```
./script.sh | tee -a output
```

to copy all the output of **script.sh** to a file called **output**, appending the text to the end of the file and displaying the text on the terminal too.

Comment: Right now I call `script.sh > logFile &`. This puts all standard output into the log file. Occasionally, I check with `tail logFile` the status of the simulation. However, all error messages written to STDERR are still printed to the Terminal and not into the file. Is it possible to apply `tee` only to STDERR?

Comment: `>` is redirection of standard output, `2>` is redirection of error output, so if you do not use `tee`, you have to type `./script.sh >output 2>error` or `./script.sh >output 2>&1` if you want standard & error output in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollback buffer is a function of your terminal or console.

If you are using the framebuffer console, it's possible to use the `fbcon=scrollback:` parameter at boot time to increase the size of the scrollback.

For the **xfce4-terminal**, go to "Edit->Settings->General->Scrollback" and change the scroll-buffer to your likings.

for kde's **konsole**, go to "Settings->Configure current Profile...->Scrolling->Fixed number of lines"

the classical **xterm** can be configured with a startup-flag -sl 777 (for 777 lines of scroll-back buffer) or via the saveLines config.

For **GNU screen**, start it with screen -h .

I'd go with screen, in which you can search the scrollback buffer:

```
/ Vi-like search forward
? Vi-like search backward
C-a s Emacs style incremental search forward
C-r Emacs style reverse i-search
```

In scrollback mode (or copy mode, it is the same) you can also copy and paste text.