# Upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.10, got the dreaded "starting version 219" error

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel, 15.04

When I try to login, it reverts me to the login screen. If I move my mouse, it shows a log of system events and then does the same thing. I can Clrl + Alt + F1 to a terminal, and do modifications from there. I've attempted several fixes, some finished, some halted due to other roadblocks.

I think the core of the problem is something to do with my Nvidia driver (vs the graphics card) and I got another error along the lines of "failure to load start kernel drivers".

Would my best bet be to reinstall from a live CD? I can give more specific info to any queries later.

Here's some output:

```
systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
[1;31m●[0m systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static;     vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: [1;31mfailed[0m (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-06-12 17:26:33     BST; 1min 17s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 419 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load [1;31m(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)[0m
 Main PID: 419 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 12 17:26:33 me-GA-78LMT-USB3 systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Jun 12 17:26:33 me-GA-78LMT-USB3 systemd-modules-load[419]: Module 'fuse' is builtin
Jun 12 17:26:33 me-GA-78LMT-USB3 systemd[1]: [1;39msystemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE[0m
Jun 12 17:26:33 me-GA-78LMT-USB3 systemd[1]: [1;31mFailed to start Load Kernel Modules.[0m
Jun 12 17:26:33 me-GA-78LMT-USB3 systemd[1]: [1;39mUnit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state.[0m
Jun 12 17:26:33 me-GA-78LMT-USB3 systemd[1]: [1;39msystemd-modules-load.service failed.[0m
```

Comment: You mentioned that you've attempted some fixes. What exactly you've done so far ?

Comment: For one I tried [this](http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/how-to-install-bumblebee-on-ubuntu.html) but couldn't do step 4 because it said something like "no such installation for bbswitch". So I couldn't progress there. I also tried adding "nomodeset" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= and deleting "quiet mode splash" but no joy at all.

Comment: Ok, login into Ctrl + Alt + F1 or F 2 , and let me know what does output of `ls -l ~/.Xauthority` look like

Comment: Ok, will have to be tomorrow from 0800 GMT though. Thanks so far!

BTW, is there a CLI/terminal logger I can install to record the output?

Comment: I attempted to write that command in exactly, but no joy. "No such file or directory".

Comment: My graphics card is actually an AMD, so I went away from trying to get Nvidia to work and looked for AMD drivers. Then I installed the latest Ubuntu desktop package. Still nothing. The thing that bothers me the most is the "failure to load kernel start modules" problem. Google has doesn't turn up much?

Comment: @Serg please help me out here, I've tried almost every other solution.

Comment: alright, I'm gonna try my best to help you. For now please post output of several logs ( dmesg, kern.log, syslog) , loaded modules (` sudo lsmod` command), and hardware info (`sudo lshw`). You can output them to files, move files to a usb, and upload to paste.ubuntu.com , then link them here. I'll ask around , there's people more knowledgeable than me. If you don't want to continue messing with the fixes, just mount a usb , backup your files with `rsync` , and reinstall the whole thing. I'll be out of town for a day, but I'll put all my efforts to help you

Comment: Cheers! Here's [dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11704426/). [loaded modules](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11704436/) and [hardware info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11704442/). I'll get the other two logs in a few mins.

Comment: Here are [kern,log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11704638/) and [syslog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11704651/).

Comment: @Serg any ideas?

Comment: I've written a sort-of answer here http://paste.ubuntu.com/11717064/  Let me know if anything works and i will post it here as official answer. I've asked around, some people said you've got hybrid graphics, which is as i understand is complicated to troubleshoot. Also, since no-one has posted an answer yet by this point, i doubt this question will get much attention later on, so just try whatever i suggested, and if all fails - reinstall 15.04 or use 14.04. Last one, 14.04 is Long Term Support. is more stable and so you shouldn't experience this issue

Comment: By the way, ,youve asked about a tool to record terminal session. There is `script`  command for that :http://askubuntu.com/a/161946/295286

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm.
```

If lightdm is already installed then...

```
sudo systemctl disable sddm.service
sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service
```

You will now see the gnome greeter and will now boot and reboot every time.