# Is it possible to see a log of all terminal output that occurred after running a command?

Tags: command-line, log

I know it's possible to see a history of all commands I've run, but is it possible to see a log of all terminal *output* that occurred after running a command?

Context is that I want to see exactly what happened when I ran a command a couple of days ago, as opposed to yesterday.

Comment: Only if you prepare (see `man script`) in advance. But, constantly using `script` will fill your disk with data. Another thing you could do, again, in advance, is open from, the menu, open `Edit->Profile Preferences`, click on the `Scrolling` tab, and click the `Unlimited` checkbox.

Comment: No, that is not possible after the fact.

Look [here on a sister site of Ask Ubuntu](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20272)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is not logged as matter of course. If it's out of your buffer (ie you have the window open still and can scroll back up), or you've closed the terminal, **it's gone**. Sorry.

In the future, there are [a couple of techniques for logging entire bash sessions](https://askubuntu.com/q/161935/449).