# Add output of script to file after it has run

Tags: command-line, output

I run a script: `python my_script.py`. It outputs a bunch of lines in the terminal. I forgot to use the output command: `python my_script.py > file.txt`. Is it possible to get the recent output to the screen into a file, other than with copy-paste?

Comment: Writing this question is probably more work then copy-paste :)

Comment: If you knew you would forget to use `>` *before* you even started ( :) ), you could use the `script` command of course. http://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash only keeps a history of the commands you entered. You can retrieve it by entering `history` Bash never stores the output of these commands , so the copy/paste option is the only hope for you.