# How to log all the output displayed at screen?

Tags: server, ssh, monitor, log

running Ubuntu 18.04 on a non headles server dedicated only to cryptocurrency mining.

The server, after some moments of mining, beeps and reboots. While it does that, there is some kind of error message that i cant get to read, is a lot like if you blink it youll miss kinda thing. It last less than a second on screen before rebooting.

I've tried checking every log at var/log and also journalctl looking for this error message with no luck. Tried to log all the output of the miner to >> minerlog.log with no luck. If i SSH to the server through putty, the error message is not shown, so logging a putty sesion doesnt work either.

My question is, then, is there a way to log all the text displayed in the monitor to a file so i can check lather whats that error message? or if a log like that alredy exists?

I;ve searched everywhere for an answer, so if this is a repeated question, do please inform me where it was repeated, thank you.

Comment: Did the word "panic" appear anywhere that you could see?

Comment: no, its really a glimpse, it last less than a second, i even tried to film it, no luck

Answer (score 0):

**script**

The standard tool is the **script** command. Here a description from the manual, `man script`:

> DESCRIPTION
>          script  makes  a  typescript  of  everything  displayed on your terminal.  It is useful for students who need a hardcopy
>          record of an interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out later with lpr(1).

If you need more **professional** tools you can search for one on this [link](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/linux-terminal-recording-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

When you are ready to start recording a log file, type:

```
script screen.log
```

Now, until you stop the script, all input and output in the Terminal will be stored in screen.log. When you are done, just type:

```
exit
```

Your screen.log file will be stored in the local directory. If you want to redirect it, use an absolute pathname such as ~/screen.log. This will do exactly what you are looking for.

See if you can add the above lines in a script that will execute as soon as the machine starts.

**Source**: [Another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/161946)