# Logging inputs and outputs in terminal without weird characters

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, logging

I'm looking for a way to log all the input and output on terminal during a session, but I can't properly find an answer to do it. This [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session) suggested using `script screen.log` to do so and it seems perfect, that's EXACTLY what I needed. However, this generate a file with very weird characters [as shown in this picture (screenshot from VIM of the file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xusWg.png). I have also tried to open it with Sublime Text and the weird characters are there as well.

I have tried this method on two different machines, one using WLS 2 with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (focal) and the other using WLS 1 with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (bionic). Both had the same result.

Is there any way to do exactly this without the weird characters?

Many thanks

Comment: Those are control sequences - they are included in the typescript file so that programs can exactly reproduce what you saw on screen. Try opening the file in `less` rather than `vim`

Comment: That actually didn't work but thanks to your tip I was able to find a solution, just type `cat typescript | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' \
                 | col -b > typescript-processed` where typescript is the name of the original log and type-script-processed is the name of the output file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Steeldriver, those are control sequences. After doing some google with this term I was able to find [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/script-command-without-junk-character) with a solution:
Just run the script command as usual
After saving the file, remove the junk characters with this command:

```
cat typescript | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' \
             | col -b > typescript-processed
```

Worked for me