# How to enable automatic logging in Terminator in Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, putty, terminator

How can we enable automatic logging to a file in Terminator just like we do in putty based terminal emulator?

In Putty we can just enable the all session output to a location - D:\putty-log&H-&Y&M&D-&t.log. Is there a similar way in Terminator?

Or can anyone suggest a good terminal (putty based) like Mobaxterm which can save session and etc for Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I log all input and output in a terminal session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session)

Answer (score 1):

Enable the logger:

1. Right click on terminator screen
2. Click Preferences
3. Go to Plugins tab
4. Enable Logger
5. Click close

Start logging:

- Right Click on terminator screen again
- Click start logger

Comment: But I want the default logging to be saved just like putty. In this case i have enable the logging every time manually.